# HighCharts Loading from CSV File with Many Data Points

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

After much searching and wanting to bang my head against my desk, I'm posting my first question on stackoverflow.

I've got an ASP.NET web application that is generating some data on the server side and creating a CSV file on the server.

I'm using HighCharts to produce a graph. Everything is working great, however, depending on what kind of date range a user runs there can be a few data points or many data points.

The problem comes in when there are many data points. Look at the X-Axis, and you'll see what I mean. Is there anyway to "group" these where it doesn't show every single point on the X-Axis?

The dates are at random intervals.

I've created a JSFiddle with my client side code and the contents of my CSV file in a JavaScript variable.

Here is my code:

```
function parseDate(dateStr) {
    var matches = dateStr.match(/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})/)
    return Date.UTC(matches[3], matches[1]-1, matches[2]);
}

var csv = 'Chart,3/4/2007,3/24/2007,4/13/2007,4/25/2007,9/19/2007,9/28/2007,11/5/2007,1/7/2008,1/14/2008,1/21/2008,1/27/2008,2/3/2008,2/10/2008,2/17/2008,2/24/2008,3/2/2008,3/23/2008,3/30/2008,4/5/2008,4/21/2008,5/3/2008,5/10/2008,5/17/2008,5/24/2008,5/31/2008,6/8/2008,6/15/2008,6/29/2008,7/4/2008,7/18/2008,7/25/2008,8/1/2008,8/8/2008,9/17/2010,11/25/2010,8/16/2012,1/17/2013,1/27/2013\nDates,180.00,175.50,167.00,166.50,170.00,171.50,174.00,163.00,162.50,164.00,166.50,166.50,167.50,170.00,170.00,171.00,169.00,166.50,166.00,166.50,162.00,160.00,160.50,162.50,164.00,164.00,165.00,165.50,166.00,169.00,171.00,170.00,171.00,165.00,165.00,189.00,177.00,175.50';

var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime',
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Pounds'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };
    // Split the lines
        var lines = csv.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(parseDate(item));
                });
            }
            else {
                var series = { 
                    data: []
                };
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                        series.name = item;
                    } else {
                        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    }
                });
                options.series.push(series);
            }
        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Here is the link to JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2hyF/6/

Thanks in Advance,

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this working and never posted the answer... Here is the answer.

Take a close look at:

**series.data.push([parseDate(points[0]), parseFloat(points[1])]);**

in the code below...

```
function parseDate(dateStr) {
    var matches = dateStr.match(/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})/)
    return Date.UTC(matches[3], matches[1] - 1, matches[2]);
}

var csv = 'Chart,11/1/2013|6,11/2/2013|4,11/3/2013|6,11/4/2013|3,11/5/2013|5,11/6/2013|5,11/7/2013|5,11/8/2013|6,11/9/2013|4,11/10/2013|13,11/11/2013|12,11/12/2013|3,11/13/2013|5,11/14/2013|7,11/15/2013|9,11/16/2013|0,11/17/2013|2,11/18/2013|3,11/19/2013|2,11/20/2013|16,11/21/2013|6,11/22/2013|9,11/23/2013|9,11/24/2013|20,11/25/2013|10,11/26/2013|10,11/27/2013|4,11/28/2013|9,11/29/2013|7,11/30/2013|7';

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sales'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: []
};

var lines = csv.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');
        var series = {
            data: []
        };
        $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
            if (itemNo == 0) {
                series.name = item;
            } else {
                var points = item.split('|');
                series.data.push([parseDate(points[0]), parseFloat(points[1])]);
            }
        });
        options.series.push(series);
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rswilley601/gtsLatyr/

Answer (score 0):

Check out HighStocks and its DataGrouping feature:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping

It can handle much larger datasets than HighCharts can. However, there are drawbacks as the newest HighCharts features are not always immediately in HighStocks. There are generally only minor changes needed to your syntax to use HighStocks, if you want to test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to get it to work with minimal changes like you said.

Do you mind looking at the JSFiddle again? http://jsfiddle.net/Q2hyF/8/

I updated it, but what is up with the dates? What am I missing, or what is wrong? It looks much better though!

Comment: Question, why are you pushing timestamps into categories? I would suspect you could reformat the data into a [timestamp, data] format like the dataset used for the main HighStocked example here: [link](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?)